# How to Access ASP control located in a user control via JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, user-controls, ascx

**Hi All,**

I'm designing a user control, briefly it contains an asp:hiddenfield control, i'm going to access it via JavaScript function like this

```
function doAnyThing
{
    var myVar = document.getElementById("myHiddenFiled");
}
```

but when I trace my code I found myVar assigned to null, does it matter

```
document.getElementById()
```

method is used in user control file (.ascx) or in regular (.aspx) file, taking into consideration it works in (.aspx) file correctly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had to set by ClientID the final id of your control, that will depend by the structure of your page.
Try this:

```
function doAnyThing
{
    var myVar = document.getElementById("<%= yourControlServerID.ClientID %>");
}
```

Obviously this function need to be placed in the .aspx file. I suggest you to switch to use a framework like jQuery, that allows you to retrieve controls by more sofisticate selectors. This case will be solved by:

```
$("[id$=yourControlServerID]");
```

and you can place your javascript code even in an external .js file.

Answer (score 2):

to simplify you can use either:

JQuery

```
$("<%= yourControlServerID.ClientID %>"). ....
```

ASP.NET JavaScript annotation:

```
var myVar = $get("<%= yourControlServerID.ClientID %>");
```

the ASP.NET JavaScript annotation code is the same as:

```
var myVar = document.getElementById("<%= yourControlServerID.ClientID %>")
```